# Trouble with my conditions statement

Tags: java, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am trying to make a condition where the user is checked by three numbers. I cannot seem to figure this out, I want to make sure the user only chooses one of these 3 numbers.

```
System.out.println("How big do you want your pizza? Enter a size of: 10, 12, or 14 inches.");
size = scan.nextInt();
while( size != 10 )  <=====(**PROBLEM**)
{
    System.out.println("That is not a valid size. Choose again.");
    size = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: In Java you can use `&&` for logical `and`.

Comment: You are checking with only one condition check all three with || operator.

Comment: @Raj I tried using || for all three and it did not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to continue looping until you get a 10, 12, or a 14, so use

```
while (size != 10 && size != 12 && size != 14) {
    ...
}
```

or [its equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
while (!(size == 10 || size == 12 || size == 14)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please, condition forest?^^

Comment: I used the first option

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] allowedSize = {10, 12, 14};

if (in_array(size, allowedSize) == false)
{
   // Size is not good
}


public static boolean in_array(Object needle, Object[] haystack) {
        return (Arrays.binarySearch(haystack, needle) >= 0);
    }
```

Comment: Uhh, I only know the basics. I appreciate this though

Answer (score 1):

In java you can use '&&' as you would 'and'.
In your case you could do:

```
size = scan.nextInt();
while( size != 10 && size != 12 && size != 13 )  <=====(**PROBLEM**)
{
    System.out.println("That is not a valid size. Choose again.");
    size = scan.nextInt();
}
```